# Uncaught (in promise) Error: "Geolocation" plugin is not implemented on android

Tags: android, vue.js, vuejs3, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Please help it's been a while and I can't solve this.

We are using **Vuejs** and **Capacitorjs v4** to build a mobile app.

In order to get the location of the user, we are using `@capacitor/geolocation` plugin from Capacitorjs official documentation, link: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/geolocation.

It works fine when I test it locally on localhost. However, when I change the web view link to the production instead of localhost I am getting this error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: "Geolocation" plugin is not implemented on android` even though it is being registered successfully as I can see the logs in the android studio:

**Logs:**

```
D/EgretLoader: The context is not activity
D/Capacitor: Starting BridgeActivity
D/Capacitor: Registering plugin: WebView
D/Capacitor: Registering plugin: AppLauncher
D/Capacitor: Registering plugin: Geolocation
D/Capacitor: Registering plugin: Preferences
D/Capacitor: Registering plugin: PushNotifications
D/Capacitor: Registering plugin: SplashScreen
```

**Code:**

```
if(Capacitor.getPlatform() != "web"){
      const coordinates = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
      finalResult = Object.assign(stringObject,{"time" : nd},{"longitude" : coordinates.coords.longitude.toString(), "latitude": coordinates.coords.latitude.toString()});
}
```

**MainActicity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {}
```

**Notes:**

*I tried all online solutions (none of them worked) such as:*

- *Manual registry of plugins in MainActivity.java file*
- *minifyEnabled false in build.gradle file*

Please help it's been like two weeks and we're still stuck on this issue.
Thank you, appreciate your help.

**Update:**
***configuration file:***

```
{
    "appId": "com.example.is.app",
    "appName": "App Name",
    "webDir": "dist",
    "bundledWebRuntime": false,
    "plugins": {
        "SplashScreen": {
            "launchShowDuration": 4000,
            "launchAutoHide": true,
            "fadeOutDuration": 1000,
            "splashFullScreen": false,
            "splashImmersive": false
        },
    },
    "cordova": {},
    "server": {
        "cleartext": true,
        "hostname": "hemera-is-dev",
        //"url": "https://www.myremotewebsite.com/app/dist/",(not working even though other plugins work normally on the remote website)
        "url": "http://localhost/app/dist/",
        "allowNavigation": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I change the web view link to the production instead of localhost"?

Comment: in the capacitor configuration file, I have a server{} that contains the hostname, URL, clear text, etc. When I change the URL from my local host to the remote host the plugin returns this error. I updated the question so you can see the file that contains the settings.